# JFace - Change font color in ToolBarManager

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have an application using a ToolBarManager and I need to change the font color of a button.

```
ICoolBarManager coolBar = ...
IToolBarManager toolBar = new ToolBarManager(coolBar.getStyle());

MyAction myAction = new MyAction();
myAction.setText("I need this text in other color"); //this is my button's description at the toolbar

toolBar.add(myAction);
coolBar.add(new ToolBarContributionItem(toolBar, "msg"));
```

I can't find a way to setStyle or setFont or something else.

How can I change the text color in a toolbar button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ToolBarManager` has a `getControl()` method which returns you the underlying SWT `ToolBar` control (note this method is only in `ToolBarManager` not the `IToolBarManager` interface).

`ToolBar` has the usual SWT `setForeground`, `setBackground`, `setFont` methods.

Note: depending on how the `ToolBarManager` is constructed the `ToolBar` may not be created until `ToolBarManager.createControl` is called.